# What is the type of the following coupled differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to learn more about systems described by differential equations of the form:

$$\begin{align}f'(x) & = c_0 + c_1 f(x) + c_2 f(x)^2 + \ldots \\ g'(x) &= d_0 \, f(x) + d_1 g(x) f(x) + d_2 f(x) g(x)^2  + \dots\end{align}$$

Both are nonlinear inhomogeneous differential equations, but the point is that the unknown function $g$ doesn't appear in the first equation.  So, it can be solved stepwise: integrate first equation, then substitute answer into second equation to get $g$.

I'd like to learn more about such systems, and how certain differential equations can be brought to this form, and a techincal name/property of this system would helpful.  I'm looking for a word that's something in between "coupled" and "uncoupled".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a system is said to be in "triangular form", in analogy with the linear system $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a triangular matrix.  Any system of ordinary differential equations can be brought to this form using a change of variables, but it's not possible to find an explicit transformation in general.  (For PDEs, it's not even possible in principle.)  If $F$ and $G$ are sufficiently simple, you might get lucky.  I will illustrate the procedure below.

To bring a system
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=F(f(x),g(x)),\\
g'(x)&=G(f(x),g(x))
\end{align}
to this form, it suffices to find a change of variables $r=R(f,g),s=S(f,g)$ such that the equation
$$
r'(x)=A(r(x))
$$
is true for some $A$, since then the corresponding system for $r$ and $s$ will be triangular.   Substituting $r=R(f,g)$, we get:
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial f}f'(x)+\frac{\partial R}{\partial g}g'(x)=A(R(f,g)).
$$
The original differential equations imply
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial f}F(f,g)+\frac{\partial R}{\partial g}G(f,g)=A(R(f,g)).
$$
For a fixed $A$, this is a partial differential equation (PDE) for $R(f,g)$.  By the usual existence theorems, a local solution can be found in principle by the method of characteristics, but an explicit solution is, in general, not possible unless $F$ and $G$ are sufficiently simple.

For example, if $F(f,g)=pf+qg$ and $G(f,g)=uf+vg$ are linear functions, then choosing $R(f,g)=af+bg$ and $A(r)=\lambda r$ is equivalent to solving the matrix eigenvalue problem $$\begin{pmatrix}p&u\\q&v\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix},$$
which just amounts to diagonalizing your linear system, or placing it in Jordan normal form.

There is also a nice class of nonlinear examples that arises when demonstrating limit cycles in dynamical systems:
\begin{align}
F(f,g)=f\Phi(f^2+g^2)-g\Psi(f,g),\\
G(f,g)=g\Phi(f^2+g^2)+f\Psi(f,g),
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are arbitrary.  Substituting $R(f,g)=f^2+g^2$ into the PDE gives:
$$
2(f^2+g^2)\Phi(f^2+g^2)=A(f^2+g^2),
$$
so $A(r)=2r\Phi(r)$.  We have thus shown that $r(x)=f(x)^2+g(x)^2$ solves the decoupled ODE:
$$
r'(x)=2r(x)\Phi(r(x)).
$$
Of course, $s(x):=\arctan(g(x)/f(x))$ solves something more complicated.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05101), which also discusses PDEs in triangular form, the phenomenon of "triangular form" is called "decoupling", but it's the same idea.   [This paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9590.2007.00363.x/abstract) shows how to solve some systems which are already in triangular form.

Comment: What a great and thorough answer!  Much more than I expected!